# MUI Swipeable edge drawer - disable drawer opening temporarily on touch

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have implemented the MUI react drawer with a swipeable edge. On mobile, I am seeing two different actions. When I touch the edge, the drawer opens temporarily.  When I swipe up on the edge, the drawer opens permanently. I would like to disable the action where the drawer temporarily opens on touch. The reason is that when I swipe up on the edge, the drawer 'flickers' because the two actions are happening at the same time.

Any ideas on how to do this?

To demonstrate this behaviour, I have included the MUI swipeable edge drawer CodeSandbox. The swipe action can be tested by opening inspect tab and toggling the device toolbar.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gfkp71?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Do you want to disable the touch edge?

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same issue and found it was solved recently by the MUI team: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/pull/34505

Comment: I had to update MUI Core: @mui/material": "^5.10.17